# Running Cygwin commands from batch file

Tags: android, cygwin, android-ndk

My project is an AndroidNDK project and requires some build commands to run from Cygwin (or a Unix environment). Is there a way to do this using TeamCity?

I tried using the commandline build step and passing in a batch file which first launches cygwin, and then performs the build commands I need. However this does not work, all it does is launch cygwin, but my unix commands do not get executed after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you launching and running commands from cygwin?

You will have to do `bash -c "command you want to run"`  (assuming bash.exe is on path). Just calling bash and then giving commands will just launch bash.

Comment: I've tried this, but this gives me some errors from the ndk-build script, ie 'line 40: dirname: command not found
ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it'.
The command I want to run from Cygwin is `$NDK_ROOT/ndk-build`. If I try `bash --login -i MyBashScript`, where MyBashScript contains `$NDK_ROOT/ndk-build`, I get a little further however then I get `Could not find application project directory ! Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH...`  Otherwise if I manually launch Cygwin and run ndk-build, all works fine.

Comment: I ended up using a bash script and calling my commands from the batch file. For some reason I have to use `bash --login -i` and then my bash script name. Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I used cygwinonce. I tried doing similar you wanted to do.I wanted to start cygwin with default command.
bash --login -i myBashScript.exe 
only when we paste myBashScript.exe in bin folder.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer.