# dirname: command not found error when I run android project - NDK

Tags: android, bash, compiler-errors, android-ndk, cygwin

I'm building an android application in eclipse. I need to call a function written in C/C++.
I setup everything including NDK, cygwin, etc (ask if u need more details), but when I try to run the project, I get this error

> **** Build of configuration Default for project C_Google_FaceDetect **********
>
> C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe C:\Android_NDK\ndk-build
>
> cygwin warning:
>
> MS-DOS style path detected:
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\John Smith\eclipse_workspace\C_Google_FaceDetect
>
> Preferred POSIX equivalent is:
>
> /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/John Smith/eclipse_workspace/C_Google_FaceDetect
>
> CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
>
> Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
>
> http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
>
> C:\Android_NDK\ndk-build: line 40: dirname: command not found
>
> C:\Android_NDK\ndk-build: line 78: uname: command not found ERROR:
>
> Unknown host operating system:
>
> ***** Build Finished **********

The project name is C_Google_FaceDetect

If I use cygwin to get the PATH, I get

> John Smith@E-USK3631BE /cygdrive/c
>
> $ echo $PATH
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/PC Connectivity Solution
>
> /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
>
> /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
>
> /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
>
> /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/nls
>
> /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/nls/ENGLISH
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/IVI Foundation/IVI/bin
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/IVI Foundation/VISA/WinNT/Bin
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/IVI Foundation/VISA/WinNT/Bin
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2012a/runtime/win32
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2012a/bin
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2010a/runtime/win32
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2010a/bin
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/emgucv 2.1.0.793/bin
>
> /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/mchi7jb2/My Documents/GLUT/lib
>
> /cygdrive/c/OGLSDK/lib
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2/Lib
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/MATLAB Compiler Runtime/v713/runtime/win32
>
> /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/QuickTime/QTSystem
>
> /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK
>
> /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK/build
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin
>
> /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK
>
> /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK/ndk-build/usr/bin
>
> /cygdrive/c/Android_SDK/tools
>
> /cygdrive/c/Android_SDK/platform-tools
>
> /cygdrive/c/Android_NDK

My Android.mk file is as follows

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := C_Google_FaceDetect
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yuv_decoder.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gonne when I used this
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i C:\Android_NDK\ndk-build
instead of this
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe C:\Android_NDK\ndk-build

in the eclipse build command

I found the answer there,[Running Cygwin commands from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881553/running-cygwin-commands-from-batch-file)

maybe the problem is only gonne because I have bigger problems now I dunno